# rbind throws away custom S3 classes

Tags: r

I have created two data.tables and provided them with a custom class. When I perform rbind on them, the result will no longer inherit the custom class. How can I make sure that the result does contain the custom class:

```
> mytable <- data.table(x = c(1,2), y = c(2,3))
> class(mytable) <- c("myclass", class(mytable))
> class(mytable)
[1] "myclass"    "data.table" "data.frame"
> result <- rbind(mytable, mytable)
> class(result)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Where I would actually like to have the result:

```
> class(result)
[1] "myclass"    "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own S3 method to keep the class.

```
rbind.myclass <- function(...) {
    res <- rbind.data.frame(...)        
    class(res) <- c("myclass", class(res))
    res
}
result <- rbind(mytable, mytable)
class(result)
```

Comment: Amazing, that would do for this specific case. Is there a way to generalize this: each time a data.table also has myclass, to make sure that it will always add myclass after performing the data.table function?

Comment: data.table function as in?

Comment: For example 'aggregate', which is strictly not a data.table function. But the same thing as my initial questions would apply here. In order for my code to remains intact I'd imagine it would be wiste override all such functions with the approach you suggest. Or can you do something like that more efficiently?

Comment: What are you trying to do ultimately? Maybe a S3 class might not be a good approach.

Comment: I have already quite a large tool working just fine. However I'm currently extending  it and noticing how much more consistent things can be with the S3 classes. There my question on how to do it for all data.ftable/frame functions is to make sure that all my code will continue to work. But your current solution will also suffice. Thanks!